# Получить URI кэшированного изображения в Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

Загружается картинка из интернета с помощью Picasso:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://dom.com/картинка.png").into(imageView);
```

После загрузки необходимо получить URI этой картинки в кэше или в памяти, вида: `file:///data/data/com.dom.myapp/cache/картинка-2387472834.png` или `memory://...........` для передачи его в другую `Activity`.

**Предоставляет ли Picasso возможность получить URI кэшированного изображения или каким способом можно его получить??**

Comment: Вот нашел тему по этому вопросу:[Надеюсь поможет](https://gist.github.com/heitara/322f4d5e9484ca1b9ec8)

Comment: @androidx К сожалению, как раз основной метод `getCachedURL()`, который мне нужен, там не описан ((